# How to add a proper Legend in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
classes=['1','-1']
colors = {1:'red',-1:'green'}
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,10))
axs.set_xlabel('X1')#Features
axs.set_ylabel('X2')#Features
axs.set_title('Scatter plot of Data Target VS Features')
plt.scatter(X[X.columns[0]],X[X.columns[1]],c=Y.map(colors),label=classes,cmap=Y.map(colors))
axs.grid(True)
legend1=axs.legend(['-1','1'],loc="lower left", title="CLass",frameon=False)
axs.add_artist(legend1)
plt.show()
```

Here above is my code to simply scatter a dataset and it was working well until it comes to Legend.
I want to set each class its related tag as Legend but I get the below result and it does not help with the red data:

As we can see we only have green data legend and not the red one:

[image]

I don't want to use `for_loop` or anything strange.
I've seen similar questions but can't figure out how to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
scatter_plot = plt.scatter(
    X[X.columns[0]],
    X[X.columns[1]],
    c=Y.map(colors),
    label=classes,
    cmap=Y.map(colors)
)

plt.legend(
    handles=scatter_plot.legend_elements()[0], 
    labels=classes,
    loc="lower left", 
    title="Class"
)
```

Comment: It still gives the same output.